# Can a line feed (hexadecimal 0x0A) be legally embedded in UTF8?

Tags: c++, c, unicode, file-format

I'm designing a simple file format, and instead of supporting only extended US ASCII, I was thinking of supporting UTF8.

The line feed byte (hexadecimal 0x0A) is one of the delimiters. Is it possible for this byte sequence to be embedded in a multi-byte UTF8 sequence? E.g., where one of the initial bytes has the high bit set (indicating a multi-byte character) and one of the trailing bytes is 0x0A?

Comment: No, as all bytes in multi-byte sequences in UTF-8 have their high bit set.

Answer (score 5):

Please look at the UTF-8 specification. All bytes with value <= 0x7F are treated as that codepoint; all bytes in a multibyte sequence have the high bit set.